# Troubleshooting font problems with XeTeX

Tags: xetex, errors, cjk

When using XeTeX, I sometimes get errors like this:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/AdobeSongStd(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/AdobeSongStd(0)/m/n' instead on input line 181.
```

As I am using CJK, the error does not seem to be telling me which character it cannot print. How do I specifically identify which character cannot be displayed?

Comment: Are you using the `CJK` package? With XeLaTeX, you should be using the `xeCJK` package instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't an error, just a warning. Nothing serious. You can ignore it safely.

With `xeCJK`, you will never use Chinese fonts for small caps shape letters. Only western fonts are used for alphabets. And for Chinese characters, there is no small capitals at all, of course.

If you do want to prevent the warnings, you can set `[SmallCapsFont=*]` option. But as a developer of `xeCJK`, I think it is redundant.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[SmallCapsFont=*]{Adobe Song Std}

\begin{document}
\textsc{The beauty of words 文字之美}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The message doesn't mean that it can't print a character. It means that the shape "sc" (small caps) is not available and that latex is using the normal shape ("n") instead. I don't know much about cjk, but probably you don't need small caps and can simply ignore the warning.